# How to use JOGL 1.x as a dependency with buildr?

Tags: java, jogl, buildr

How can I declare JOGL 1.x as a dependency of my Java project when using Buildr?

Answer (score 0):

Is JOGL on a Maven repository ? You should upload it to yours if it's not publicly available.

Then it's the usual:

```
# Example of artifact definition, granted that JOGL's group id jogl, 
# and the artifact id is jogl.
#
# I put up 1.0 as version too. 
JOGL = "jogl:jogl:jar:1.0"

...
compile.using JOGL
```

You can also install JOGL locally and point to it:

```
compile.using _("lib/*")
```